# ¿Cómo implementar un buscador de cualquier campo para el index.ctp en cakePHP 3.6?

Tags: cakephp

---

Tengo cuatro tablas (Locales, Rutas, Trayectos y Programaciones):

Tabla Locales:

```
   id   |   nombreLocal
--------------------------
    1       Local Uno
    2       Local Dos
    3       Local Tres
```

Tabla Rutas:

```
   id   |   id_ruta_origen   |   id_ruta_destino
--------------------------------------------------
    1             1                    2
    2             2                    3
```

Tabla Trayectos:

```
   id   |   id_trayecto_origen   |   id_trayecto_destino
--------------------------------------------------------
    1             1                    3
    2             3                    1
```

Tabla Programaciones:

```
   id   |   id_rutas   |   id_trayectos
------------------------------------
    1          1             1
    2          2             1
```

Tengo las siguientes asociaciones:

En la tabla Locales:

```
$this->hasMany('Rutas', ['foreignKey' => 'id_ruta_origen']);
$this->hasMany('Rutas', ['foreignKey' => 'id_ruta_destino']);
$this->hasMany('Trayectos', ['foreignKey' => 'id_trayecto_origen']);
$this->hasMany('Trayectos', ['foreignKey' => 'id_trayecto_destino']);
```

En la tabla Rutas:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Origen', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_ruta_origen',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Destino', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_ruta_destino',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Programaciones', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas'
    ]);
```

En la tabla Trayectos:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Origen', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_trayecto_origen',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Destino', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_trayecto_destino',
        'className' => 'Locales',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Programaciones', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_trayectos'
    ]);
```

En la tabla Programaciones:

```
 $this->belongsTo('Rutas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_rutas',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

$this->belongsTo('Trayectos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id_trayectos',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

> Intento programar un form control (input) para buscar por nombres de
>   locales tanto en rutas como en trayectos desde el index.ctp del
>   controlador Programaciones; pero lo que he avanzado es filtrarlo por código:

En la accion index del controlador Programaciones tengo esto:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        if (isset($this->request->data['PrgSearch'])) {
            $conditions = $this->request->data['PrgSearch'];

            $programaciones = $this->paginate($this->Programaciones->find('all', [
                'conditions' => ['Programaciones.id' => $conditions],
                'contain' => ['Rutas' => ['Origen', 'Destino'], 'Trayectos' => ['Origen', 'Destino']]
            ]));

            $this->set(compact('programaciones'));
            debug($programaciones);
        }
    }else{
        $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Rutas' => ['Origen', 'Destino'], 'Trayectos' => ['Origen', 'Destino']]
        ];
        $programaciones = $this->paginate($this->Programaciones);

        $this->set(compact('programaciones'));
    }
}
```

Y en el index.ctp del template de Programaciones tengo esto:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($programaciones) ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('PrgSearch', ['label' => 'Buscar', 'placeholder' => 'Buscar Programación']);
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Buscar', ['action' => 'index'])) ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Y lo que quisiera obtener algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ciertamente fue un caso interesante, pensé que se podía solucionar con algunos contains y joins pero me di cuenta que sería muy complicado por como están definidas las relaciones. En fin te dejé una respuesta espero te sea de utilidad, no te olvides votarla positivo o negativo según lo consideres necesario y un comentario en caso de alguna duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única forma en la que se me ocurre puedes hacerlo es buscar las *Rutas* y *Trayectos* por separado y luego pasarlo como condición a la búsqueda de las *Programaciones*.

Para aprovechar la paginación podemos enviar el texto de la busqueda como un parámetro *GET*, para eso pasamos como parámetro, de esa forma:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($programaciones, ['type' => 'get']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('PrgSearch', ['label' => 'Buscar', 'placeholder' => 'Buscar Programación']);
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Buscar', ['action' => 'index'])) ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

El código en el controlador mencionando ciertas partes importantes:

```
public function index()
{
    $conditions = [];
    $contain = [
        'Rutas' => ['Origen', 'Destino'],
        'Trayectos' => ['Origen', 'Destino'],
    ];

    if (!empty($this->request->getQuery('PrgSearch'))) {
        $searchText = $this->request->getQuery('PrgSearch');

        // Buscamos todas las rutas que contengan el string deseado
        $rutas = $this->Programaciones->Rutas->find('list')
            ->contain(['Origen', 'Destino'])
            ->where([
                'OR' => [
                    'Origen.nombreLocal LIKE' => "%$searchText%",
                    'Destino.nombreLocal LIKE' => "%$searchText%",
                ]
            ])->toArray();

        // Buscamos todos las trayectos que contengan el string deseado
        $trayectos = $this->Programaciones->Trayectos->find('list')
            ->contain(['Origen', 'Destino'])
            ->where([
                'OR' => [
                    'Origen.nombreLocal LIKE' => "%$searchText%",
                    'Destino.nombreLocal LIKE' => "%$searchText%",
                ]
            ])->toArray();

        // Le pasamos como condición los id's previamente encontrados
        if (!empty($rutas)) {
            $conditions['OR'][] = ['Rutas.id IN' => array_keys($rutas)];
        }
        if (!empty($trayectos)) {
            $conditions['OR'][] = ['Trayectos.id IN' => array_keys($trayectos)];
        }

        // Si no existen ninguna ruta o trayecto pasamos como id 0 para ser
        // consistente y no mostrar ninún registro
        if (empty($rutas) && empty($trayectos)) {
            $conditions = [
                'Programaciones.id' => '0'
            ];
        }
    }

    $this->paginate = [
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain' => $contain,
    ];
    $programaciones = $this->paginate($this->Programaciones);
    $this->set(compact('programaciones'));
}
```

---

Enlaces importantes:

- [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)
- [Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)

Comment: Está exlente @KacosPro; pero me sale un error dando a entender que no generará el paginate con condiciones vacías, más pare el caso de Trayectos.

Comment: Super @KacosPro, funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias man.

Comment: De nada tocayo ;)